# How to print/log that a child in Process is done?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using python's `multiprocessing.Process` to parallelize; is there a simple way to find out when each child job is done? For example, this is how I currently implement my code:

```
def func(k):
  print(42*k)

q = mp.Queue()
processes = [mp.Process(target=func, args=(k, q)) for k in keys)]

for p in processes:
  p.start()  # start each
for p in processes:
  p.join()  # wait for all to come back

result = [q.get() for _ in processes]  # collect
```

What I want is `print "{} done".format(k)` right as each child joins the parent.

Why do I want this? A couple of my processes take longer than the others, so I want to see of they finished or not before all of the processes return. The easiest (but not so clean) solution is to print the message inside `func()`; but I would rather do it in the parent module.

Comment: where is `func(k)` used?

Comment: Good catch. That is the target. Modified code to reflect that.

Comment: The call to `p.join()` could come *long* after the process actually completes, if a previous call blocks a faster process from being joined. You are better off doing the logging from the child processes.

Comment: @chepner Good point! I am currently doing the logging from the child processes. Thanks.

Comment: @liliscent the `Queue` is used in the collection of the results. This is a barebones code that I extracted from a large codebase. So strange might describe it.

Comment: Just posting some garbage code in your question isn't good enough. Please [edit] it an put in something that's at least _close_ to being executable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for concurrent.futures -https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

There are many things subtle in joining concurrent tasks, and a lot of things to improve, like having a pool of worker process that match the number of cores on you machine, and reuse those processes --
The `concurrent.futures` does ll that allowign a choice of using threads or process to execute each task.

So, what you want would be something like:

```
In [19]: import concurrent.futures, time, random
    ...: executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4)
    ...: def func(n):
    ...:     time.sleep(random.random())
    ...:     return n
    ...: futures = [executor.submit(func, i ) for i in range(10)]
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [20]: for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    ...:     print(fut.result())
    ...:     
6
3
7
5
2
8
4
9
0
1
```

(I used ThreadPoolExecutor in order for the example to run on the interactive interpreter here - you will want to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPollExecutor` instead)

Comment: Thanks, this looks intriguing! I'll ping back.